# How can I attach VS Code Debugger to a Chrome browser tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I want to attach the debugger to a chrome browser tab.

### Tests

#### Content

I tested with this config:
**launch.json**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't work.

##### Error

> Cannot connect to the target at localhost:0: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:0: Could not find any debuggable target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your chromium browser telling it to listen for debuggers on a specific port.

See [the VS Code docs for attaching the debugger to browsers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_attaching-to-browsers).

> To attach to a running browser, it needs to be launched in a special debug mode. You can do this using the following command, replacing edge.exe with the path to your Edge or Chrome binary:
>
> ```
> edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile
> ```
>
> Setting the `--remote-debugging-port` tells the browser to listen on that port for a debug connection. Setting a separate `--user-data-dir` forces a new instance of the browser to be opened; if this flag isn't given, then the command will open a new window of any running browser and not enter debug mode.
>
> Next, add a new section to the vscode/launch.json file as below:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "version": "0.2.0",
>   "configurations": [
>     {
>       "type": "msedge",
>       "request": "attach",
>       "name": "Attach to browser",
>       "port": 9222
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> Now, you can press F5 or the Start button in the Run and Debug view to attach to the running browser. You can even add a host property to debug a browser running on a different machine.

Related docs for the now-superseded Chrome debug extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#attach.

Comment: Thanks for the link!
They deprecated for this extension https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug

Comment: But the instructions for running Chrome aren't in the new repo, but yours.